# Counterpart to date range

Tags: antonyms, dates

I am searching for a word that expresses the "opposite" of a date range.

My ideas so far are the following:

- Timestamp
- Moment

But neither of them really satisfies me. I need the word for a programming task, and therefore it would be nice, if the word would be as similar as possible to "date range", so that the wording alone already implies the same topic.

Do you have other suggestions?

EDIT:

With opposite or counterpart to "date range" I mean a word (or short phrase), that expresses one specific day/date instead of a range of days. The range spans in contrast to that specific day multiple days and the range has a start and an end date.

My ideas do not satisfy me because they do not imply the same topic or any relation to "date range". Timestamp or Moment is hard to be said to be the direct opposite of date range. As an example "timestamp" can be easily identified as the counterpart to a "time range".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming software variables is off-topic.

Comment: @JEL datestamp sounds reasonable to me. Didn't know, that this word exists.

Comment: @Chenmunka Sorry! Just saw that you are right. If I remove the note that it is a programming question, Would it then be a valid question? Or is there another stackexchange site, where I can ask this question?

Comment: If you don’t need a single word, then “precise date,” “actual date,” or “exact date” (taking “exact” from @davidlol ’s answer) could work. Although it would probably cause more confusion than its shortness is worth, for a single word you could consider using “[D-day](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/d-day)” in its generic sense ("3. Informal. any day of special significance, as one marking an important event or goal").

Comment: Please edit your question to articulate what sense of "opposite" you're after, and why your two ideas don't satisfy that sense.

Comment: @Lawrence please see the edit.

Comment: @exilit That's much better. How about just the word "date"?

Comment: I think I,ll go with @JEL's siggestion. if you make your comment an answer, I will accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your constraints, it sounds as if 'datestamp', 'date-stamp' or 'date stamp' might work. Of those, 'date-stamp' is a verb, as defined by *Collins English Dictionary* and the *OED Online*:

> *vb* (tr)
>   to mark (an object) with an inked impression of a date

[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. S.v. "date-stamp." Retrieved February 17 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/date-stamp ]

> *trans.*
>   To mark with a date stamp.

["date-stamp, v.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/298068?rskey=wqwyHV&result=2&isAdvanced=false (accessed February 17, 2016).]

I suspect, however, that you are looking for a noun. The former and still-in-use noun is open (no hyphen), 'date stamp':

> *n*
>   1. (Commerce) an adjustable rubber stamp for recording the date
>   2. (Commerce) an inked impression made by this

[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014. S.v. "date stamp." Retrieved February 17 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/date+stamp ]

> A stamped mark indicating the date, esp. of the posting or receipt of a letter, parcel, bill, etc.; an adjustable stamp used to make such a mark.

["date stamp, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/298070?rskey=wqwyHV&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed February 17, 2016).]

To me, the definitions of the open form noun from *Collins* and *OED Online* seem at least incomplete, and the definition of the closed form noun from *Wiktionary* seems up-to-date for the computer era:

> **Noun**
>   **datestamp** ‎(*plural* **datestamps**)
>   (computing) The date on which an event occurred, often included in a log to track the sequence of events.

(From [*Wiktionary*, "datestamp"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/datestamp).)

Answer (score 1):

'Instant' or 'exact instant'  seems to me to convey more precisely than moment what you want to say.